# How to do integer interval arithmetic?

Tags: sets, intervals, discrete

How to calculate union, intersection and complement of integer intervals without actually generating all integers in the range and perform set-arithmetic (`Union`, `Intersection`, `Complement`) on them?

For simplicity, I  define an integer interval as a list of disjoint `{min, max}` subintervals, each covering a consecutive range of integers. I expect the following output, each being the **minimal** representation of the interval:

```
union[{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, {{4, 7}, {10, 17}}] == {{-2, 7}, {10, 20}}

union[{{-2, 3}, {4, 7}, {15, 20}}] == {{-2, 7}, {15, 20}}

union[{}, {{}, {}}] == {}

intersection[{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, {{4, 7}, {10, 17}}] == {{15, 17}}

complement[{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, {{4, 7}, {10, 17}}] == {{-2, 3}, {18, 20}}
```

I have tried the followings (for `union`).

`Interval`-s are real-valued hence they do not merge:

```
IntervalUnion @@ (Interval /@ {{-2, 3}, {4, 7}, {15, 20}})

(* Interval[{-2, 3}, {4, 7}, {15, 20}] *)
```

Inequalities representing neighbouring intervals are not always simplified:

```
FullSimplify[Or @@ (First@# <= x <= Last@# & /@ {{-2, 3}, {4, 7}, {15, 20}}), x \[Element] Integers]

(* -2 <= x <= 3 || 4 <= x <= 7 || 15 <= x <= 20 *)
```

`Solve` returns elementary solutions (regardless of the region represented as `Interval` or `ImplicitRegion`:

```
r = RegionUnion @@ (ImplicitRegion[First@# <= x <= Last@# && x \[Element] Integers, x] & /@ 
    {{-2, 3}, {4, 7}, {15, 20}});
x /. Solve[x \[Element] r, x, Integers]

(* {{-2}, {-1}, {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {19}, {20}} *)
```

Of course one can work around any of these shortcomings by structural manipulation of the results, but I am interested in whether there is a polished domestic (undocumented) solution or not.

Comment: Maybe you should look at implementing an [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)

Comment: For your Inequality example, applying [`LogicalExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogicalExpand.html) before `FullSimplify` seems to help.

Answer (score 2):

## <s>Solution</s>  The OP says this does not answer the question.

You can transform your list of `{min, max}` into [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) explicitly specifying [`Integer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integer.html) domain.

### List to region

```
ClearAll[intInterval];
intInterval[{a_Integer,b_Integer}]:= ImplicitRegion[ And[ a <= x <= b, Element[x,Integers] ], x]
intInterval[{il___List}] := RegionUnion@@ Map[intInterval, {il}]
```

## Tests

Now we can run the checks using [`RegionEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionEqual.html).

### Union

Using [`RegionUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html)

```
RegionEqual[
    RegionUnion[
        intInterval@{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, 
        intInterval@{{4, 7}, {10, 17}}
    ] ,
        intInterval@{{-2, 7}, {10, 20}}
]
(* True *)
```

### Intersection

Using [`RegionIntersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html)

```
RegionEqual[
    RegionIntersection[
        intInterval@{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}},
        intInterval@{{4, 7}, {10, 17}}
    ],
    intInterval@{{15, 17}}
]
(* True *)
```

### Complement

Using [`RegionDifference`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDifference.html)

```
RegionEqual[
    RegionDifference [
        intInterval@{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, 
        intInterval@{{4, 7}, {10, 17}}
    ],
    intInterval@{{-2, 3}, {18, 20}}
]
(* True *)
```

## Region simplify

```
ClearAll[regionSimplify];
regionSimplify[ir_ImplicitRegion]:=ImplicitRegion[
    And[
        Element[ir[[2,1]],Integers],
        FullSimplify[
            ir[[1,2]]
            , Element[ir[[2,1]],Integers]
            , ComplexityFunction-> Function[expr, LeafCount[expr]-500*Count[expr,LessEqual]+50*Count[expr,Or]]
        ]
    ]
    ,{x}
]
```

## Region to list

```
region2list[ir_ImplicitRegion]:=ReplaceAll[
    regionSimplify[ir][[1]]
    , {Or->List,Inequality[a_,LessEqual,x,LessEqual,b_]->{a,b}, x\[Element]Integers->True }
]
```

Comment: This is nice, but it circumvents the problem. What I need is not the ability to compare the resulting interval to any other interval, but to have a list of disjoint subintervals like `{{min1, max1}, {min2, max2}, ...}`. Implicit regions do not simplify the inequalities.

Comment: Yeah, but compare `FullSimplify[x \[Element] Integers && (-2 <= x <= 3 || 4 <= x <= 7 || 10 <= x <= 17 || 15 <= x <= 20), x \[Element] Integers]` with `FullSimplify[x \[Element] Integers && (-2 <= x <= 3 || 4 <= x <= 7 || 15 <= x <= 20), x \[Element] Integers]`.

Comment: I want to maintain a minimal representation of the interval. Either `{{-2, 7}}` or `-2 <= x <= 7`, it does not matter, but certainly not `-2 <= x <= 3 || 4 <= x <= 7`. However, simplification does not always yield the minimal form as my above example demonstrates (I've added this to my post).

Comment: @IstvánZachar check the edit and the definition of `regionSimplify` and `region2list`.

Comment: I have the feeling, that relying on `Simplify` and `LogicalExpand` (perhaps `Reduce`), one can get rid of the `Region`-overhead entirely, at least for union. However, it is still very messy, as any resulting inequality is not standardized and can be of many forms (`Less`, `LessEqual`, `Greater`, `GreaterEqual`, `Inequality`, etc., especially if `Infinity` (- and +) is allowed), which all require structural identification to convert to boundaries.

Comment: @IstvánZachar, sure, but this is as much as I have time to share. Sorry I couldn't answer what you needed

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented some rudimentary functions to do this.

Integer intervals are represented as defined above: a list of disjoint, ordered boundary pairs of integers (or +/- infinity). Each function assumes that the input is already numerically sorted, each subinterval is numerically ordered and subintervals are not overlapping.

These functions are far from being optimal, but already orders of magnitude faster than relying on `Region` arithmetic or `Simplify`-ing inequalities. Please feel free to suggest improvements.

```
ClearAll[intervalUnion, intervalIntersection, intervalDifference];

$pos = _Integer | ∞ | -∞;
$int = {$pos, $pos};

intervalUnion[set:$int, add_] := intervalUnion[{set}, add];
intervalUnion[{}, add:$int] := {add};
intervalUnion[set:{__List}, {}] := set;
intervalUnion[set:{__List}, {min:$pos, max:$pos}] := Which[
   max < set[[1, 1]] - 1, Prepend[set, {min, max}],
   min > set[[-1, -1]] + 1, Append[set, {min, max}],
   True, Module[{n = Length@set, i = 1, minQ = True, maxQ = True, from, to},
    to = n;
    While[(minQ || maxQ) && i <= n,
     If[minQ && set[[i, 2]] + 1 >= min, minQ = False; from = i];
     If[maxQ && set[[i, 1]] > max + 1, maxQ = False; to = i - 1];
     i++];
    Insert[Drop[set, {from, to}], {Min[min, set[[from, 1]]], 
      Max[max, set[[to, 2]]]}, from]]];
intervalUnion[{}] := {};
intervalUnion[set:{__List}] := Fold[intervalUnion, set];
intervalUnion[set:{___List}, add:{___List}] := intervalUnion@Join[set, add];


intervalIntersection[_List, {}] := {};
intervalIntersection[{}, _List] := {};
intervalIntersection[{amin:$pos, amax:$pos}, {bmin:$pos, bmax:$pos}] := 
  If[amax < bmin || amin > bmax, {}, {Max[amin, bmin], Min[amax, bmax]}];
intervalIntersection[a:$int, b:{$int..}] := intervalIntersection[{a}, b];
intervalIntersection[a:{$int..}, b:$int] := intervalIntersection[a, {b}];
intervalIntersection[a:{$int..}, b:{$int..}] := 
  DeleteCases[Flatten[Outer[intervalIntersection, a, b, 1], 1], {}];


intervalDifference[{}, _List] := {};
intervalDifference[all:$int, set:$int] := intervalDifference[all, {set}];
intervalDifference[all:$int, {} | {{}}] := {all};
intervalDifference[all:$int, set:{$int..}] := intervalIntersection[
   all, (# + {1, -1} & /@ Partition[Flatten@set, 2, 2, {-1, 1}, {∞, -∞}])];
intervalDifference[all:{$int...}, set:{$int...}] := 
   Flatten[intervalDifference[#, set] & /@ all, 1];
```

Testing:

```
intervalUnion[{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, {{4, 7}, {10, 17}}]
(* {{-2, 7}, {10, 20}} *)

intervalUnion[{{-2, 3}, {4, 7}, {15, 20}}]
(*  {{-2, 7}, {15, 20}} *)

intervalUnion[{}, {{}, {}}]
(* {} *)

intervalIntersection[{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, {{4, 7}, {10, 17}}]
(* {{15, 17}} *)

intervalDifference[{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, {{4, 7}, {10, 17}}]
(* {{-2, 3}, {18, 20}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could represent the interval $[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Z}$ as $[a,b+1[$, i.e. you take the interval over the reals with the upper bound extended to just below the next integer. This has the advantage that intervals that "touch" over the integers also "touch" over the reals, meaning everything is automatically simplified.

While `Interval` doesn't support open intervals, you can use inequalities and use `Reduce` to do all the heavy lifting. Concretely, implementing your examples:

```
intervalConstr[x_][{ints : {_Integer, _Integer} ...}] :=
 Or @@ (# <= x < #2 + 1 & @@@ {ints})
intervalConstr[x_][ints : {_Integer, _Integer} ...] :=
 Or @@ (# <= x < #2 + 1 & @@@ {ints})

toIntervals[x_][a_ <= x_ < b_] :=
 {a, b - 1}
toIntervals[x_][segs_Or] :=
 List @@ (toIntervals[x, #] & /@ segs)
toIntervals[_][False] :=
 {}

union[ints__] :=
 toIntervals[x]@Reduce[Or @@ intervalConstr[x] /@ {ints}]
intersection[ints__] :=
 toIntervals[x]@Reduce[And @@ intervalConstr[x] /@ {ints}]
complement[inta_, ints__] :=
 toIntervals[x]@
  Reduce[intervalConstr[x]@inta && And @@ Not@*intervalConstr[x] /@ {ints}]

union[{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, {{4, 7}, {10, 17}}]
(* {{-2, 7}, {10, 20}} *)

union[{}, {}]
(* {} *)

intersection[{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, {{4, 7}, {10, 17}}]
(* {15, 17} *)

complement[{{-2, 3}, {15, 20}}, {{4, 7}, {10, 17}}]
(* {{-2, 3}, {18, 20}} *)
```